# Utilizar int y char en pipes en c

Tags: c, pipe

¿Se pueden transmitir números enteros (int) y caracteres (char) por la misma
tubería o se necesita crear dos tuberías distintas? Cómo seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para un entero sería algo así:

```
int n = 45;
write(pipe, &n, sizeof(n));
```

Y para una cadena de caracteres así:

```
const char* cad = "una prueba";
write(pipe, cad, strlen(cad) + 1);
```